# Why doesn't it get any data?

Tags: java, android, sql

Main:

```
ColegiListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColegDataEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Id", Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(id)));
                Log.i("Id",id+"");
                startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this).toBundle());
            }
        });
```

DATABASE HELPER:

```
public Cursor getSpecificData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this. getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TableName + " WHERE ID ="+id, null);
    return data;
}
```

SECOND ACTIVITY:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    int id =intent.getIntExtra("Id",0);
        Cursor data = mDatabase.getSpecificData(id);
```

Hi! I am a beginner with SQL and I don't know what I did wrong. I have a database with multiple columns and I need to get some data from it so then I can put those values in some TextViews. The problem is that the data I need needs to be a single row with the specific id from an item from a ListView (yeah, I now about row id, I solved that problem). Any ideas why isn't it working?

Comment: Have you tried your query directly against the database to see that it works and verify that there is some data for the given id? And why is the table name a variable, looks overly complicated?

Comment: Could you write the code, please?

Comment: What is the type of ID?

Comment: You already have the query, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your Database Helper

```
public Cursor getSpecificData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TableName + " WHERE ID = "+id;
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return res;
}
```

In Activity make a setViewsfunction

```
public void setViews() {
            Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getSpecificData(id);
            try {
                if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        textview1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_1_NAME)));
                        textview2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_2_NAME)));
                        //and so on

                    }

                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the try method, but the problem isn't that. It just doesn't work! All seems ok, but the cursor is null.